# MongoDB find() returns less results than specific query

Tags: mongodb

I have been doing MongoDB query on my users collection to verify if one specific field is set by previous script. It returned 21862 users.

```
> db.usersProfiles.find({'currentTutorialState':{$ne:''}}).count()
21862
```

However, odd is, when I use *find* without any parameters, it returns **less** users! How is it so?

```
> db.usersProfiles.find().count()
21860
```

Edit: Please advise that this is **not** the difference between find().count() and count(), as the results are different and I don't know why the query for existing field returns more than full find().count().

Comment: 2 users were deleted?

Comment: Two clarifications: 1: do you get the same answer from `db.usersProfiles.count()` ? 2: is the usersProfiles collection sharded, and if so, what results do you get when you run those queries through mongos vs through an individual shard?

Comment: Alex: no, the results are reproducable.

Comment: Vince: 1. db.usersProfiles.count() gives 21860. 2. no, it is single database server

Comment: Maybe, it is because of unclean shutdown. Run db.runCommand( { validate: "usersProfiles", full: true } ) and then check the count.